# iTextSharp - How to extract PDF pages with various columns

Tags: itext

can someone provide a code snippet that lets you open a PDF file and read a page that starts with 1 column and then change to 2 columns?

For example (the lines can vary): 
Page 1
 - Line 1  to 10 - 1 column
 - Line 11 to end- 2 columns

Each page can vary the number of columns.

PS: I know the width of each column (if necessary).

Thank you,

Comment: You may need to implement your own text extraction strategy. The `LocationTextExtractionStrategy` would be a good base but you'd have to change the `getResultantText(TextChunkFilter)` method: It sorts the chunks top-to-bottom, left-to-right which is ok for you for the first 10 lines. Thus, you have to consume the chunks for the first 10 lines like the original implementation does, but then you'd have to sort the remaining text chunks once again using a `Comparator` which takes the columns into account.

Comment: Thank you MKL, 
you have a snippet about it to be able to provide?